# python forked processes not executing with os.execlp

Tags: python, macos, exec, fork

I've got this simple python script that ought to fork new processes and then have each execute a command using os.execlp, but the execution only occurs once. I'm curious if there's a timing issue going on that is preventing the additional forks from executing:

```
import os

for n in range(5):
    PID = os.fork()
    if PID == 0: #the child...
        print("This child's PID is: %s" % os.getpid())
        os.execlp('open','-n','-a','Calculator')
        # os.popen('open -n -a Calculator')
        # os._exit(0)
    else:
        print("new child forked: %d" % PID)
```

For this, the "open -n -a Appname" command in OS X launches a new instance of the specified application, so the above code should replace the forked process with the "open" command, and this should run 5 times. However, it only runs once so only one instance of Calculator is opened. Despite this, the parent lists 5 child PIDs forked.

If I comment out the os.execlp line and uncomment the os.popen and os._exit lines following it, then this works properly and the child processes all run the "open" command; however, I am wondering why the approach of replacing the forked process using execlp (or execvp and other similar variants) is not working? Clearly the child process is running, as I can use piping to run the "open" command just fine.

This is with python 3.4.3.

Comment: From the Python website: "These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current process; they do not return. On Unix, the new executable is loaded into the current process, and will have the same process id as the caller."

If you are replacing your process, it would make sense that you could only have one instance running.

Comment: @StevenMorad, The os.fork() command will split off a child process from the current process, giving the child a new PID. This process will see its own PID as 0, so when it is split off and runs, it will execute os.execlp (whereas the parent will not). This should result in os.execlp only replacing the code of the child, and not the parent. As such, the parent should run 5 times and fork 5 child processes (as it does). The problem was ultimately not seeing that os.execlp requires the full argument string, inclusive of arg[0] for the specified command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument, after the executable, is arg[0] which is by convention the name of the executable. This is useful, if you have symbolic links, which determine the behavior of the programm. In your case, you name the programm `'-n'` and the real arguments are only `-a` and `Calculator`. So you have to repeat `'open'`:

```
os.execlp('open', 'open', '-n', '-a', 'Calculator')
```

Comment: Ah I see...I was seeing the argument list as not being inclusive of arg[0]. Thanks!